# Can i put special characters like ® in the .resx file?

Tags: asp.net

I have created a ProductResources.resx file. The name and value fields contain the ® character. THis is the R with a circle around it. It is a reg trademark. Obviously this needs to be there. An the resource file itself gives a red circle with a question mark inside it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what you must do:

- add a app_local_resources folder(right click on your project --> add asp.net folder)
- name the resource folder as the following: PageName.aspx.resx
- add the button name and property ( eg. Button1.Text) in the resource file name field
- copy (by just highlight the registered trade mark from any source and copy it, paste in the value field [from here](http://usefulshortcuts.com/alt-codes/intellectual-property-alt-codes.php)
- go to your button and add the following such as:

  ```
   asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="" onclick="Button1_Click" meta:resourcekey="Button1"
  ```

[alt text http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/2108/59469768.jpg](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/2108/59469768.jpg)

hope this is what you want :)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the encoding you declare for the resx XML, you can probably use one of the following:

```
   &#174;      (iso-8859-1  or utf-8)
   &#8482;     (unicode)
```

Comment: I have seen other documents that use &reg;           
Can I use this instead and also what does it imply

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think &reg; is only for html, where the other examples may be more universal.

Comment: Yes, &reg; is an HTML only thing.  Assuming there is not additional conversion done on the client side, and assuming this is be rendered in an html context, you could use "&amp;reg;", without the quotes.  Since &reg; is not a valid XML entity, its ampersand (&) is escaped as &amp;  This should then come as "&reg; at the "other end".